# Android in-app subscription with variable amounts

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have to develop an Android App which will allow the user to perform some tasks, and depending on the tasks performed, the app will charge user a monthly fee. And that monthly fee can be of variable amount, not a fixed amount.

I have studied [In-App SUbscriptions](http://android.cn-mirrors.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html) and [Google Play Developer API](https://developer.android.com/google/play/developer-api#subscriptions_api_overview) but nothing such there.

In-App subscriptions API though allows differing payments, which I believe is a way to allow to skip few subscription renewals (as trial or reward) but nothing like a variable renewal amount.

Please suggest if any way this is possible? Or what could be an alternate solution?

EDIT (1):

As for using a non-Google subscription system, this doesn't seem allowed as explained in [In-App SUbscriptions](http://android.cn-mirrors.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html).

> Apps published on Google Play that are selling subscriptions must use
>   In-app Billing to handle the transaction and may not provide links to
>   a purchase flow outside of the app and Google Play (such as to a web
>   site).

Comment: I don't think google allows such subscriptions plan yet, also they have lots of issue in existing apis(currently we are using it ) but  razorpay provide such subscription plan where you can set min payment and add the extra topup. You can use the other payment gateway. Google allow them